# Trouble with constant buffers

Tags: c++, directx-11

im trying to use constant buffers in d3d11 but turns out that when the shader multiplies the pos vector with the matrix it doesnt return anything and i get a black screen,i have tried everything that i found on tutorials but i had nothing,here is the code:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC udesc;
ZeroMemory(&udesc,sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
udesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
udesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
udesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(uniformsperobj);
udesc.MiscFlags = 0;
udesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
hr = dispositivo->CreateBuffer(&udesc,NULL,&uniformbuffer);
//draw frame function//
    model = XMMatrixIdentity();
    campos = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    camtarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    camup = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    view = XMMatrixLookAtLH(posdecam, objdecam, arrdecam);
    proyection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.4f * 3.14f, (float)WINDOW_WIDTH /WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1.0, 1000.0f);
    XMMATRIX MVP = model*view*proyection;
    upo.MVP = XMMatrixTranspose(MVP);
    context->UpdateSubresource(uniformbuffer,0,NULL,&upo,0,0);
    context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&uniformbuffer)
/*
********************************shaders.fx***********************************************
*/

cbuffer uniformesporobjeto
{
    float4x4 MVP;
};

struct vertex
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};


vertex vshader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    vertex output;

    output.Pos = mul(position, MVP);
    output.Color = color;

    return output;
}

float4 pshader(vertex input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

sorry if i posted too much code but the problem is that i dont really know were the error is because im stupid

Comment: Did you enable debug layer? Have you tried debugging with Renderdoc for example?

Comment: i am already using the debug layer but i will try renderdoc,thanks for answersing

Comment: and debug layer says nothing?

Comment: ,,,,,,,,,,yes :(